# Generating non-final classes from Protobuf

Tags: java, protobuf-java

I am using Protobuf in one of my Java projects and recently came across a use case that requires extending Protobuf generated class. From the documentation, it appears that the classes generated will always be immutable (Class generated with final keyword). Is there a way to generate the non-final classes with Protobuf?

Will appreciate someones response over it. Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a description of how you generate the protobuf files. Also include a description what you already have tried to remove the `final` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of extending the Protobuf generated classes, you could
create a wrapper class. In other words, you could opt for composition over inheritance. This is also the recommended approach from the Protobuf library.The wrapper class could be initialized with the generated class in the constructor and access the generated class as needed.

Protobuf intentionally adds the `final` keyword in generated classes to prevent inheritance. See the **Important** part in the [Protobuf java tutorual](https://protobuf.dev/getting-started/javatutorial/)

> Protocol Buffers and Object Oriented Design Protocol buffer classes
> are basically data holders (like structs in C) that don’t provide
> additional functionality; they don’t make good first class citizens in
> an object model. **If you want to add richer behavior to a generated
> class, the best way to do this is to wrap the generated protocol
> buffer class in an application-specific class**. Wrapping protocol
> buffers is also a good idea if you don’t have control over the design
> of the .proto file (if, say, you’re reusing one from another project).
> In that case, you can use the wrapper class to craft an interface
> better suited to the unique environment of your application: hiding
> some data and methods, exposing convenience functions, etc. **You should
> never add behavior to the generated classes by inheriting from them**.
> This will break internal mechanisms and is not good object-oriented
> practice anyway.

This is highlighted in the original documentation so such usage is officially discouraged.

Comment: +1, this is the way to go. Let `protoc` do its thing, and if you need to extend it, wrap it.
@Junaid could you go into detail, in what way you need to extent the generated class?